# Connecting application to a single notebook in Evernote, supportLinkedSandbox parameter

Tags: evernote, evernote-app-notebook

I am trying to limit access to one nootebook using supportLinkedSandbox=true parameter as it is described here:

http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/app_notebook.php

It seems this paramerter has no effect on sandbox environment.

https://www.sandbox.evernote.com/OAuth.action?oauth_token=...]&preferRegistration=true&supportLinkedSandbox=true

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `supportLinkedSandbox=true`, the notebook sandboxing feature needs to be enabled for a particular API key. You can request enabling this feature by writing to devsupport at evernote dot com.

Comment: Indeed, in order to enable this feature you need to write to support.